# Bigcommerce - Display Certain Message/Image on a specific Category/Product

Tags: javascript, php, e-commerce, product, bigcommerce

I'm fairly new to Big Commerce and had a question on how I'd be able to display an image / certain message on a specific category.

I currently have a free shipping image being displayed on all products but there's a certain category that I do not want that snippet of code being displayed.

How would I be able to achieve this?

The way I have the free shipping image being displayed is by modifying the card.html file

templates > components > products > card.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider inserting the image via banner on specific categories.
After this you can inject css via jQuery or override with plain css to display the banner wherever you like.

yourstore.xyz/manage/marketing/banners/create

**Edit 1**

Wrapping your div to if also should solve your issue on displaying that image in certain products.

```
{{#if product.shipping}}
{{#if product.shipping.price.value '===' 0}}
   <img class="yourImgClass">{{imgURL}}
{{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

**Edit 2**

Here's the JS way to remove some elements from your specific categories:

```js
var url = location.href; 

if ( url.indexOf( 'your-url' ) !== -1 ) { 
document.getElementById('your-free-shipping-image-id').remove();
console.log("yay, image bye");
}
else {
console.log("nay, image stays");
}
```

**Edit 3**
This is sort of a shift-make workaround with limited knowledge on jQuery. This would be much easier if you could place ID's on image wrapping span elements but I think you'll be alright with this.
Place this on footer, inside  brackets.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var s = $('img[src*="https://cdn7.bigcommerce.com/s-7iywz/product_images/uploaded_images/free-shipping-banner.jpg"]');
var url = location.href;
console.log(s.length);

if ( url.indexOf( 'framed' ) !== -1 ) {
s.remove();
}
});
```

Comment: Because I'm trying to modify the card.html file which affects the product view page of all products. https://ibb.co/m0pYTT If you see the image I have the free shipping image and what I'm trying to do is on some of the products not to display that free shipping image by modifying the card.html file.

Comment: I think I understand you. If your variable to bind is free shipping value that's coming from the product, You'll need to wrap that image div to an if helper. I'll update my answer to include this.
This way you won't display that image on items with no free shipping.
But, if the original question still holds place, I'd utilize jquery to remove those in certain categories.

Comment: Hello, Thanks I don't think I'm trying to bind the free shipping value the card.html file is universal for all products so whatever is in the card file shows up on all products and basically what I was trying to do with the if statement was if your in this category don't show this image else show the image. but some reason the code I've been given hasn't worked. I just tried your code as well and it made everything disappeared the free shipping img isn't being shown on any products now.

Comment: Hey @Angel you have probably mis implemented the URL portion. The URL should be your category URL, the one that you don't want the images to be displayed at. 
For example in our store the category URL is: "xyz.com/emergency-vehicle-lights"
So what I would need to use in the script would be: ...url.indexOf('emergency")....

Comment: If you can provide your store URL and the category in which you don't want the images to be displayed, I think can help you better.

Comment: Hello this is the store url and cateogry which I do not want to show the free shipping image on.
http://mtdvanities.com/mirrors/wood-framed-mirrors/

The Category ID is 70

Comment: I tried this but it was a no go. `<script>
var url = location.href; 

if ( url.indexOf( 'http://mtdvanities.com/mirrors/wood-framed-mirrors/' ) !== -1 ) { 
document.getElementById('https://cdn7.bigcommerce.com/s-7iywz/product_images/uploaded_images/free-shipping-banner.jpg?t=1525811996&_ga=2.165904830.1847420277.1525706943-52562068.1494873040').remove();
console.log("yay, image bye");
}
else {
console.log("nay, image stays");
}
    
    
    
    </script>`

Comment: Well :) Everything is wrong on that script, your image or containing span does not have IDs or classes so you can't get them by the id or class. Only thing you can do is to get them by the attribute. Hold on a minute. I'll take a look at your website.

Comment: @Angel I'm updating the answer with some shiftmake workaround. It should work.

Comment: thanks! but it's still a no go, i added it but it didn't do anything. =/ I also tried switching "framed" with "wood-framed-mirrors"

Comment: @Angel, jQuery is not defined. When you open your dev console on chrome you'll see the error: "$ not defined"

<script type="application/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Go to admin>footer scripts & paste this there.

Comment: it's working now! :) thanks! just confused as to why the if statement wasn't working.

Comment: Cool! You're welcome. Then this post deserves to be selected as answer ha :)

Comment: yes indeed! :) just tried +1 it as well but it wouldn't let me.

Comment: Awesome! I think you need to have 15 reps to do that. I'm glad it helped. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You could try exempting that category (via ID or name) in particular with a conditional statement.

As an example, you might try:

```
{{#unless category.id '==' 5321}}
    Free shipping!
{{/unless}}
```

Or for if/else:

```
{{#if category.id '==' 5321}}
    No free shipping!
{{else}
    Free shipping!
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Thanks for that input! 

I got something working but how would something like this work 

`if product == 333 
show this 

else show that.`

Comment: So after trying the code you provided "Free Shipping" was being displayed across all the categories.

Comment: Updating example above with if/else

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Also there was a glitch with your code

You had `{{/unless}} instead of {{/if}}`

So this is what I used:

`{{#if category.id '==' 70}}
    No free shipping!
{{else}}
    Free shipping!
{{/if}}`

[I've attached the Category ID which is 70](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6DLS.png)

Everything on the store still shows the Free Shipping

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove "Free Shipping" from single category then use below code and get it fixed.

```
{{#if id '!=' 70 }} Free Shipping Message}} {{/if}}
```

If it doesn't work for you then i suggest you to post the "Card File" code here so that i can check what exactly you have written in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<article class="card {{#if alternate}}card--alternate{{/if}}">
<figure class="card-figure">
    {{#or price.non_sale_price_with_tax price.non_sale_price_without_tax}}
        {{#if theme_settings.product_sale_badges '===' 'sash'}}
            <div class="sale-flag-sash">
                <span class="sale-text">On Sale!</span>
            </div>
        {{else if theme_settings.product_sale_badges '===' 'topleft'}}
            <div class="sale-flag-side">
                <span class="sale-text">On Sale!</span>
            </div>
        {{else if theme_settings.product_sale_badges '===' 'burst'}}
            <div class="starwrap">
                <div class="sale-text-burst">On Sale!</div>
                <div class="sale-flag-star"></div>
            </div>
        {{/if}}
    {{/or}}
    {{#if demo}}
        <img class="card-image lazyload" data-sizes="auto" src="{{cdn 'img/loading.svg'}}" data-src="{{getImage image 'productgallery_size' (cdn theme_settings.default_image_product)}}" alt="{{image.alt}}" title="{{image.alt}}">
    {{else}}
    <div class="card-image-container">
        <a href="{{url}}">
            <img class="card-image lazyload" data-sizes="auto" src="{{cdn 'img/loading.svg'}}" data-src="{{getImage image 'productgallery_size' (cdn theme_settings.default_image_product)}}" alt="{{image.alt}}" title="{{image.alt}}">
        </a>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
</figure>
<div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">
        {{#if demo}}
            {{name}}
        {{else}}
            <a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
        {{/if}}
    </h4>
    <div class="card-text" data-test-info-type="price">
        {{#or customer (if theme_settings.restrict_to_login '!==' true)}}
            {{> components/products/price price=price customer=customer}}
        {{else}}
            {{> components/common/login-for-pricing}}
        {{/or}}
    </div>
    <p class="card-text" data-test-info-type="productRating">
        <span class="rating--small">
            {{> components/products/ratings rating=rating}} <span style="color:gray;">{{#if num_reviews '>' 0}}</span>
   &nbsp; ({{num_reviews}}) Review{{#if num_reviews '>' 1}}s
{{/if}}{{/if}}
        </span>
    </p>
{{#if id '!=' 70 }}
<span><img src="https://cdn7.bigcommerce.com/s- 7iywz/product_images/uploaded_images/free-shipping-banner.jpg?t=1525811996&_ga=2.165904830.1847420277.1525706943-52562068.1494873040"></span>
{{/if}}
</div>
</article>
```

i have modified your code, just copy it and paste it in your theme.

Comment: thanks, but I've tried that before and that doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure what's going on =/